# custom fields for html drop down list

Tags: javascript, html

I am having a drop down list with company names populating from the database. I also want to add the custom fields like the compID, Latitude Value, Longitude Value along with the company name. So that i can use these fields ot check if a company has lat, long values if not allowing the user to add them.... and so on.

below is my html code:

```
<select id="select_comp" class="dropdown-toggle" style="width:auto;" >
            <option>Choose a number</option>
</select>
```

below is how i am populating the dropdown list:

```
            var el = document.createElement("option");
            el.textContent = data[key]["name"];
            select.appendChild(el);
```

i want custom fields something like this:

```
            el.field1 = data[key]["CompID"];
            el.field2 = data[key]["lat"];
            el.field3 = data[key]["log"];
```

Is this the right way of doing this........ if my approach is wrong please correct me....

I tried `//el.id= data[key]["CompID"];` to get the company id it worked but how to get the *lat*, *lon* values... thank You

Answer (score 0):

You can only store single values in dropdown options.

You want to populate the dropdown options with the value set as the company key/ID (real selected value) and text as the company name (what is displayed to the user):

```
el.value = key;
el.text = data[key]["name"];
```

And then when an option is selected (or any other time) you can look up the additional fields in your `data` array:

```
var dropdown = document.getElementById("select_comp");
var key = dropdown.options[dropdown.selectedIndex].value;
alert(data[key]["lat"]);
```

Comment: its a good solution but not in my case .... because i cant pass the _data_ to a JavaScript function for some reasons... so it gives me _data_ undefined...

Comment: Can you not change where `data` is defined to widen the scope?